# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: the number of constructors

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, groovy, java-8

I'm pretty new to Java and I'm trying to get around API testing with rest assured. 
I tried my code with the following pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.yourcompany.restassured</groupId>
    <artifactId>restassuredtest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
            <artifactId>libfb303</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
            <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
            <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

ending up with this error- java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: the number of constructors during runtime and compile time for com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$EncodingTarget do not match. Expected -1 but got 2

I googled a lot for a solution, but nothing worked. One of the reasons, according to my understanding is that the rest assured version and groovy version don't match. But I feel the versions are ok in this case. I'm using Java 8, JDK 1.8 on IntelliJ 2016.1.1
I'd really appreciate if you could help me out of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Rest Assured FAQ](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/FAQ) clearly states in it's example that:

**Groovy Needs to be the same version that REST Assured depends on**

Looking at the maven.pom file for the version of REST Assured you are using (2.9.0), the version of Groovy it depends on is: **Groovy 2.4.4**. But you have your set to 2.4.6. Change the Groovy version in your pom file to eliminate the issue.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
  <!-- Needs to be the same version that REST Assured depends on -->
  <version>2.4.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<properties>
    <scm.branch>master</scm.branch>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <groovy.version>2.4.4</groovy.version>
    <gmaven.version>1.5</gmaven.version>
    <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
    <jackson1.version>1.9.11</jackson1.version>
    <jackson2.version>2.4.3</jackson2.version>
    <maven-javadoc.version>2.9.1</maven-javadoc.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I assumed anything >2.4.4 would work. However, its now returning `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
 at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:117)
`, though I'm not using testng

Comment: Actually, changing the version and pom file didn't fix it :/

Comment: @pam So, where are you now? Are you getting the same error after changing the version or the new error shown in your comment?

Comment: Was your NoClassDefFoundError related to your other question and answered there?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36443730/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-though-testng-is-not-imported

Comment: I had multiple versions of groovy, so it was picking up the wrong one. Its working now. Thanks a ton!