# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, though testng is not imported

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, testng

I'm trying rest assured API testing with the following code,

```
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import com.jayway.restassured.http.ContentType;
import com.jayway.restassured.mapper.ObjectMapper;
import com.jayway.restassured.response.Response;
import jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.when;
import static com.jayway.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.from;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItem;

public class apiTestj {
    public static Response response;
    public static String jsonAsString;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupURL() {
        // here we setup the default URL and API base path to use throughout the tests
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://api.wunderground.com";
        RestAssured.basePath = "/api/dddd88ab2ff59656/geolookup/";
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void callZipcodeAPI() {
        response =
                when().
                        get("/q/77001.json").
                        then().
                        contentType(ContentType.JSON).  // check that the content type return from the API is JSON
                        extract().response(); // extract the response
        // Convert the JSON response to a string, and save it in a variable called 'jsonAsString'
        jsonAsString = response.asString();

    }

    @Test
    public void checkAllCities()
    {
        //System.out.println(jsonAsString);

        List<String> airport_cities = from(jsonAsString).get("location.nearby_weather_stations.airport.station.city");
        System.out.println(airport_cities.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < airport_cities.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(airport_cities.get(i));
        }

        String c = from(jsonAsString).get("location.nearby_weather_stations.airport.station[-1].city");
        System.out.println("The last element in the list : " + c);

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");


        List<String> pws_neighborhood = from(jsonAsString).get("location.nearby_weather_stations.pws.station.neighborhood");
        System.out.println(pws_neighborhood.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < pws_neighborhood.size(); i++) {
            //System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(pws_neighborhood.get(i));
        }



    }

}
```

and the following pom file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.yourcompany.restassured</groupId>
    <artifactId>restassuredtest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
            <artifactId>libfb303</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
            <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
            <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <!-- Needs to be the same version that REST Assured depends on -->
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <scm.branch>master</scm.branch>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <groovy.version>2.4.4</groovy.version>
        <gmaven.version>1.5</gmaven.version>
        <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
        <jackson1.version>1.9.11</jackson1.version>
        <jackson2.version>2.4.3</jackson2.version>
        <maven-javadoc.version>2.9.1</maven-javadoc.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

ending up with this error, though I didn't import testng-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

I'm using Java 8, JDK 1.8 on IntelliJ 2016.1.1. I'd really appreciate if you could help me out of this.

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ to run the tests, check that the run configuration is a JUnit one, not a TestNG one

Comment: I think that is the problem. I don't know how I overlooked it. Thanks much!

Comment: TestNG is able to run JUnit tests, so it should work. As `org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter` is an IntelliJ class, you should open an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues